# Parameters in Query With FORMAT Funtion

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have the WHERE clause in my query that goes like

```
WHERE (FORMAT([salesdate], "yyyy") = @year;
```

Then I added the parameter @year like this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@year", (year)));
```

It should filter records that has sales date according to a chosen year. But it returns nothing. I'm sure that my variable year got it right. I'm also sure that the Parameter.Add is on the right place.

I also tried the same query on MS Access, with input value for the parameter, then it worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, [salesdate]) = @year;
```

There is a different way of adding parameters, you can try that in combination with DATEPART:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = year;
```

Comment: Not sure, I think it could be because the FORMAT function returns a string. What type is @year?

Comment: Integer. I'll try to parse it to string

Comment: Well FORMAT is intended to format a date as a string, DATEPART is what you really want there, extract the Year part of the date. I would use DATEPART

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. But when I put direct variable or sonething like 2016 in the query, it does work. I just want to use params..

Comment: can you add your whole code? also which dbms are you running it against?

Comment: I think it will do. Thanks mate

Comment: Hi. The problem is not the FORMAT, data type, etc. I used datediff and then one @date parameter for all (daily,weekly,monthly, yearly) queries, and it works with datediff. Before that, I used one parameter for selected day/week/month/year. But after working on a different function, I discovered myself that parameters is not like variables you can used anytime on queries, but it works depending on their sequence. No-one said it works that way so I'm happy to learn it.